# jquery, losing track of this after I call a different function. What is going on?

Tags: jquery

I have a listener that looks like this:

```
$(coin_form_wrapper).on('click', '.remove_address_button', function(e) {
    debugger;
    remove_input_row(e)
  });
```

At the debugger, `$(this).parent()` is the correct div, or at least the div that I expect.

```
$(this).parent()
w.fn.init [div, prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
```

However, inside my function, the value of `$(this).parent()` is now the window:

```
function remove_input_row(e) {
    // no longer works or references the correct div
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  }
```

this is what I get:

```
$(this).parent()
w.fn.init [prevObject: w.fn.init(1)]
```

How do I fix this? Why is this happening?

The fix is doing this inside my function:

```
$(e.target).parent('div').remove();
```

Is there any other way? This feels.... not great since now this function is dependent on `e` being passed into it always. Is this a problem?

Comment: Aren't you already passing `e` anyway?

Comment: I am and I know the solution... but is this kosher? If I wanted to keep using this, is there a way?

Comment: It looks like better form to me than passing `e` but not using it.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on assumptions like that in a function anyway.  Just pass the function what it needs.

Comment: `this` is very strict about context, you can pass down `this` as an argument after `e` and then use it as `_self` in the function itself

`remove_input_row(e,this)`

`function remove_input_row(e,_self)`

Comment: `this` is relative to its scope. If you wanted to maintain `this` throughout deeper calls, you'd have to pass it along as a parameter each time and reference that instead.

Comment: `this` is *not* relative to its scope except in the case of arrow functions. In all other situations, the value of `this` is a result of how the function is called. The value of any parameter is a result of how the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to do some work in understanding [the `this` keyword in javascript](http://georgemauer.net/2017/08/03/on-this-in-javascript.html)

In short - `this` is a parameter, like any other. The only special thing is when you invoke a (non-arrow) function `likeThis()`, the javascript language picks the value for you. Otherwise, you can always invoke functions `likeThis.call(valueOfThis, arg1, arg2)` and it will be 100% unambiguous.

So when you call

```
remove_input_row(e)
```

then that is equivalent to either

```
remove_input_row.call(window, e)
```

or - if you are in `use strict` mode -

```
remove_input_row.call(undefined, e)
```

That is why the above happens.

Because `this` is so confusing, I generally recommend people avoid it whenever possible. With jquery it is almost always possible! By using `e.target` or `e.currentTarget` you can get the element that you *really* mean with zero confusion. In your case, how about just passing that directly to `remove_input_row`?

```
const remove_input_row = (el) =>
    //closest is probably better than parent here
    $(el).closest('div').remove();
```

...

```
remove_input_row(e.target)
```

(Note that while the arrow function is not necessary, I do recommend it any time you do not absolutely need `this` - its just simpler that way.)

Comment: Is there a way for you to explain why inside the nested function, `this` is the value of `window`? Why does that happen?

Comment: @Jwan622 you might want to check my linked article but in short the rule is that `this` will be set to `window` if you do `fn()`, `undefined` if you do `fn()` while in strict mode, `a` if you do `a.fn()` (and `fn` is a property on `a`), and will just plain not exist in the function's scope if `fn` is an arrow function

Comment: I guess I'll also note that when doing `new SomeFunction()` then within that function, `this` will be a newly constructed `Function` object with its internal `[prototype]` set to the external prototype property of `SomeFunction`. That function object is returned provided that execution of `SomeFunction` returns `undefined`. And that insanity is why nobody should ever use `new`. I don't care what every stupid tutorial says, or that they added `class` to the language. Don't use features that you don't understand.